# Difference between Exception and SQLException

Tags: java, sql, exception, sqlexception

Can someone explain the difference between catching an `Exception` and catching an `SQLException`? I know that SQLException will print out more information if you choose to print out the exception errors, but is there anything else?

```
try {
   //code
} catch(Exception ex) {
   //code
}
```

And

```
try {
   //code
} catch(SQLException ex) {
   //code
}
```

What are the benefits and differences of using `Exception` and `SQLException` in the catch block?

Comment: Exception is a more general type, being a parent of SQLException. And it is used in contexts related to SQL and databases rather than in a general context. It is important to use exceptions related to the activity occurring... meaning with good code you're probably more likely to see an SQL Exception with SQL type things...

Comment: "I know that SQLException will print out more information if you choose to print out the exception errors" No. Whether you catch it in a variable of type Exception or catch it in a variable of type SQLException, it's still the same SQLException object and will contain the same information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the only difference.

Catching `Exception` is dangerous because it also catches all [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)s (therefore unchecked exceptions), and that include niceties such as `NullPointerException` etc which are clear programmer errors. *Don't do that*!

Also, `Exception` is a class like any other, so you can subclass it and add constructors/methods of yours. For instance, `SQLException` has a [`.getErrorCode()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode--) which `Exception` does not have. If you only catch `Exception`, you cannot access this method.

In general, catching the "more precise" exception first is the best. For instance, with the new (in Java 7...) file API, you can easily distinguish between filesystem level errors and other I/O errors, since `FileSystemException` extends `IOException`:

```
try {
    something();
} catch (FileSystemException e) {
    // fs level error
} catch (IOException e) {
    // I/O error
}
```

Comment: So SQLException would be an instance where you are catching something more specific and not generic?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And it is always preferrable to catch more specific exceptions first! If you catch "too low", you may catch undesirables.

Comment: That makes complete sense, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Note also that if you implement/override a method which is declared to `throws A`, you can choose to make your implementation throw `A` or any subclass.

Answer (score 3):

It's all about the hierarchy,when you are talking about the catching the exception.

Technically speaking, Exception - is the super class which catches each and every exception. 
If you are writing something related to SQL in the try block and you know it may even throw SQL Exception. 
    Then you may declare it this way as well.

```
        try
        {

        }catch(SQLException ex)
        {
        Do this,when SQL Exception is caught.
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        Generic Exception - works for all
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`SQLException` inherits from `Exception`, so `SQLException` will contain more (and more specific) information than `Exception` (which is intended  to apply generally to all exceptions).

You can also have multiple `catch` clauses; so you can first try to catch the `SQLException`, but if it's not a `SQLException`, then you can just catch the general `Exception`.

In general, you shouldn't `catch` exceptions unless you intend to handle them in some way.  You can have a top-level exception handler that catches any exceptions that bubble up to the top of the call stack, so that your program doesn't crash on unhandled exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

#### A - Explanation

`SQLException` is a subtype of `java.lang.Exception` and also it is implementing the `Iterable<Throwable>` class. Programmers prefer throwing different subtypes of `Exception` class because on some higher level, they want to catch the exact sub-Exception class so that they can be sure that that specific Exception is thrown on some exact scenario. Thus, they can know the exact source of Exception.

#### B - Example

Consider you have written a method that throws multiple exceptions. Let's say, you take a json String and parse it, then persist it on the database. Consider the following method;

```
public boolean persistCustomer(String jsonString) throws SQLException, IOException {
    Connection conn = getConnection(); 
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;


    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        Customer customer = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Customer.class);

        preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(PERSIST_CUSTOMER);

        preparedStatement.setString     (1,  customer.getName());
        preparedStatement.setInt        (2,  customer.getAge());
        preparedStatement.setBoolean    (3,  customer.getIsRegular());

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (preparedStatement != null)
                preparedStatement.close();
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In this method, we are converting JSON into a Customer class and also we persist customer class to the database.

The following lines throw `SQLException`;

```
    preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(PERSIST_CUSTOMER);

    preparedStatement.setString     (1,  customer.getName());
    preparedStatement.setInt        (2,  customer.getAge());
    preparedStatement.setBoolean    (3,  customer.getIsRegular());

    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

`prepareStatement()`, setters and `executeUpdate()` methods, all of them throwing `SQLException`'s. But also, the line that which we convert JSON in a String into a Customer object, also throws several Exceptions other than SQLException.

```
Customer customer = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Customer.class);
```

`readValue()` method throws `JsonParseException`, `JsonMappingException` and also `IOException`. All of them can be catched using an `IOException` because the JSON related exceptions extend `IOException`.

I'm going to provide two different examples so that it will be obvious to understand why we need different types of Exceptions.

#### C - Bad Practice: Using Exception To Catch All Exceptions

```
public class BadPracticeExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySQLUtil dbUtil =  new MySQLUtil();

        String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"Levent\",\"age\":31,\"isRegular\":true}";

        try {
            dbUtil.persistCustomer(jsonString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("A problem occured");
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, it catches the Exception but what are we going to do if we need special exception handling for two different sources of problems? persistCustomer can throw either IOException or an SQLException and what if we need to do different set of tasks to handle those problems? I want to send an email to the database admin when an SQLException occurs and I want to continue when a JSON parsing problem occurs, on the case that an IOException is catched?

In this scenario you can't do that. Here is the output of the code snippet above and we are only sure that an Exception occured but we don't have any idea about what is the source of it;

```
A problem occured
```

#### D - Good Practice Example I: SQL Exception catched

```
public class GoodPracticeExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySQLUtil dbUtil =  new MySQLUtil();

        String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"Levent\",\"age\":31,\"isRegular\":true}";

        try {
            dbUtil.persistCustomer(jsonString);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception catched, SQL State : " + e.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("Error Code                       : " + e.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error Message                    : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot parse JSON : " + jsonString);
            System.out.println("Error Message     : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, we catch for both, JSON and SQL problem and in this example, submethod is trying to persist DB where there is no table. The output is as below;

```
SQL Exception catched, SQL State : 42000
Error Code                       : 1142
Error Message                    : INSERT command denied to user 'levent'@'example.com' for table 'CUSTOMER'
```

So we have catched SQL Exception and we have all parameters we need to send an alarm email. We can add additional handler or utility methods on the SQLException catch block.

#### D - Good Practice Example II: IOExceptoin catched on Parsing Error

```
public class GoodPracticeExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySQLUtil dbUtil =  new MySQLUtil();

        String jsonString = "{\"Zname\":\"Levent\",\"age\":31,\"isRegular\":true}";

        try {
            dbUtil.persistCustomer(jsonString);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception catched, SQL State : " + e.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("Error Code                       : " + e.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error Message                    : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot parse JSON : " + jsonString);
            System.out.println("Error Message     : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

If you've noticed, I"ve corrupted the JSON to cause an IOException. Now in the json string, instead of "name", "Zname" is written which will cause Jackson Parser to fail. Let's checkout the output of this code.

```
Cannot parse JSON : {"Zname":"Levent","age":31,"isRegular":true}
Error Message     : Unrecognized field "Zname" (class com.divilioglu.db.utils$Customer), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "isRegular", "name", "age"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"Zname":"Levent","age":31,"isRegular":true}"; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.divilioglu.db.utils.MySQLUtil$Customer["Zname"])
```

As you can see, we catched the specific scenario and we are sure, this comes from the line in dbUtil.persistCustomer() method which can be seen below;

```
Customer customer = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Customer.class);
```

#### E - Conclusion

So as it is a best practice to create new Exceptions by extending existing Exception classes. While writing your code at first, you may think that it is an overkill and you won't need additional Exception classes, but you will need them when you need distinguish the source of the problem and handle them independently.

In this example demonstrated above, I can independently catch `IOException` and `SQLException` and the sources of both Exceptions are coming from the same method. I want to distinguish both so that I can handle them independently. You cannot have that flexibility if you just wrap all the Exceptions with the base Exception class.

Answer (score 0):

[Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) is a standard class from which every exceptions inherit.

[SQLException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) is a class that inherits from Exception and that is designed specifically for database(SQL) exceptions.

By doing

```
try {
    // Your code here
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Catching here
}
```

You are catching every type of exception possible... But then, you might not be able to know how to react to a specific exception.

but by doing

```
try {
    // Your code here
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // Catching here
}
```

You know that the exception happened while working on a database and it helps you know how to react to the exception.

Answer (score 0):

As you see [SQLException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html)  extends exception. So that's the only difference really. When you are catching exception then you will catch ALL exceptions (which is bad). But when you are catching SQLException then you catch only that(which is good because that is what you are seeking).

Answer (score 0):

If an exception in between the try and catch blocks is thrown that is not a SQL Exception (these will typically only come from database-related code), for example a Null Pointer Exception, the Exception catch will catch it but the SQLException will not.

Answer (score 0):

SQLException is an Exception so you are just getting a more specific exception.

According to Oracle's javadocs, this specific information you get is:

- a string describing the error. This is used as the Java Exception
  message, available via the method getMessage.
- a "SQLstate" string, which follows either the XOPEN SQLstate
  conventions or the SQL:2003 conventions. The values of the SQLState
  string are described in the appropriate spec. The DatabaseMetaData
  method getSQLStateType can be used to discover whether the driver
  returns the XOPEN type or the SQL:2003 type.
- an integer error code that is specific to each vendor. Normally this
  will be the actual error code returned by the underlying database.
- a chain to a next Exception. This can be used to provide additional
  error information.
- the causal relationship, if any for this SQLException.

Answer (score 0):

`SQLException` is a specialized exception derived from `Exception`.

If you catch `Exception`, all exception shall get caught. Even undesirable exceptions.

If you catch only its specialiazation, the `SQLException`, only the `SQLException` itself or its derived shall get caught.

One shall catch only exceptions one can handle or wishes to handle, and let the others bubble up.

For further reference, please take a look at the following:

1. [**Exception**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)
2. [**SQLException**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html)

Answer (score 0):

SQL exception  is a frequent error while working in Java Database Connectivity (JDBC).Its related to accessing or setting column in your SQL Query using prepared statement.

SQLException is a derived from Exception and contains more specific information related to accessing or setting column in your SQL query, while exception is usually more general.