# MySQL Record does not save

Tags: java, mysql

I have a problem with inserting a record into mySQL database, the query simply does not get executed and I don't understand why it does not print any errors when catching an exception. Any ideas please?
I have checked the spelling many times and the table itself, the connection also works because it is used in my Login Window which appears before the one shown below.

```
public class RegisterStudent implements Initializable{

@FXML
TextField txtID;
@FXML
TextField txtFirstName;
@FXML
TextField txtSecondName;
@FXML
TextField txtGender;
@FXML
TextField txtDOB;
@FXML
TextField txtAddress;
@FXML
TextField txtPostCode;
@FXML
TextField txtMobileNumber;
@FXML
Button btnRegister;
@FXML
Button btnClear;

Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

// Set Clear Button.
@FXML
private void setBtnClear() {
    txtID.clear();
    txtFirstName.clear();
    txtSecondName.clear();
    txtGender.clear();
    txtDOB.clear();
    txtAddress.clear();
    txtPostCode.clear();
    txtMobileNumber.clear();
}
// Set Register Button - Saves student record to database.
@FXML
private void setBtnRegister(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        if(txtFirstName.getText().trim().isEmpty() || 
        txtSecondName.getText().trim().isEmpty() || 
        txtGender.getText().trim().isEmpty() || 
        txtDOB.getText().trim().isEmpty() || txtAddress.getText().trim().isEmpty()
                || txtPostCode.getText().trim().isEmpty() || txtMobileNumber.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            DBUtilities.showErrorMsg("Error:", "All fields must be populated!");
        }else {
            connection = DBUtilities.getConnection();
            String SQLQuery = "INSERT INTO student_details ('First_Name', 'Second_Name', 'Gender', 'Date_Of_Birth', 'Address', 'Post_Code', 'Mobile_Number')" + " VALUES (?, ?, ? ,? ,? ,? ,?)";
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQLQuery);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, txtFirstName.getText().trim());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, txtSecondName.getText().trim());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, txtGender.getText().trim());
            preparedStatement.setString(4, txtDOB.getText().trim());
            preparedStatement.setString(5, txtAddress.getText().trim());
            preparedStatement.setString(6, txtPostCode.getText().trim());
            preparedStatement.setString(7, 
            txtMobileNumber.getText().trim());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            DBUtilities.showInforMsg("Record Saved", "Record has been saved 
    successfully!");
        }
    }catch (Exception exception) {
        //DBUtilities.showErrorMsg("Error:", "Record could not be saved!");
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        DBUtilities.closePreparedStatement(preparedStatement);
        DBUtilities.closeConnection(connection);
    }
}
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    btnRegister.setOnAction(this::setBtnRegister);
}
}
```

Comment: You certainly have to give at least some sort of error message. If nothing else, put a breakpoint in the catch block and check manually for the exception type and exception message.

Comment: I got rid of the brackets and nothing. What do you mean by breakpoint?

Comment: You should be catching [SQLException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) rather than Exception to be able to find out exactly what's going wrong. See answers on [Difference between Exception and SQLException](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22944978/205233).

Answer (score 0):

Try, `connection.commit;` after `preparedStatement.executeUpdate();` this statement. May be the autocommit is false.

Comment: The table has ID column which is set to auto increment could this possibly be the problem?

Comment: try upgrading the driver and check if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues like this before. So assuming that your table has an integer-based primary key, which should be set to auto-increment, the failure to insert the record might be due to statement:

`preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQLQuery);`

Try replacing this with:

`preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query, preparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);`

And when your code performs the insert, test for the key generated by MySQL:

```
 try {
     int noRows = ps.executeUpdate();            
     if (noRows == 1) {
         ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
         if (rs.next()) {

             // Get the newly generated primary key from MySQL.            
             int id = (int) keyResultSet.getInt(1);  

             // Call setter method for primary key's attribute in Java student_details object.
         }           
     }
 }
 catch(SQLException ex) {                  
     ex.printstackTrace();
 }
```

This has solved the problem for me in the past. And, make sure that you have a recent copy of `MySQLConnector-X.X.X.jar` in your project's build path or folder.